# Javascript - User input through HTML input tag to set a Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, input, user-input

I want there to be a textbox on my screen(like the one i'm typing in now) that you can type in then click a submit button and it sends whatever you typed in the box to javascript and javascript prints it out.Here is my code This is the part that works.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="userInput"=>give me input</input>
    <button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
    <script>
        function test()
        {
            var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
            document.write(userInput);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

OK so that's nice, but lets say I want input from that textbox and button while I'm already in a function and don't want to restart the function?

Thanks, 
Jake

Comment: I really don't get what you're talking about in you last sentence. I mean at all. You're **already in a function** and **don't want to restart** it. What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: So that code I have works if I want to initiate a function with it, but I want the submit button to essentially work while a function is already running. What attribute would I add to the button to do that? The current start the "test()" function will not work because I don't want to start the function over.

Comment: do you mean you want a function that loops waiting for input? that doesn't work in javascript. Other than that, you can use `document.getElementById("userInput").value` whenever and wherever you like.

Comment: Do not use document.write it is evil google for innerHTML and reformat your code...

Comment: Learn to attach event handlers rather than using inline "onclick" definitions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When your script is running, it blocks the page from doing anything.  You can work around this with one of two ways:

- Use `var foo = prompt("Give me input");`, which will give you the string that the user enters into a popup box (or `null` if they cancel it)
- Split your code into two function - run one function to set up the user interface, then provide the second function as a callback that gets run when the user clicks the button.

Comment: Thanks, I will just split it up into 2 functions

Answer (score 5):

This is bad style, but I'll assume you have a good reason for doing something similar.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="userInput">give me input</input>
    <button id="submitter">Submit</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
        var didClickIt = false;
        document.getElementById("submitter").addEventListener("click",function(){
            // same as onclick, keeps the JS and HTML separate
            didClickIt = true;
        });

        setInterval(function(){
            // this is the closest you get to an infinite loop in JavaScript
            if( didClickIt ) {
                didClickIt = false;
                // document.write causes silly problems, do this instead (or better yet, use a library like jQuery to do this stuff for you)
                var o=document.getElementById("output"),v=document.getElementById("userInput").value;
                if(o.textContent!==undefined){
                    o.textContent=v;
                }else{
                    o.innerText=v;
                }
            }
        },500);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript works best when it's event driven, rather than having a monolithic do-all loop. You should only do this if it's absolutely necessary that things happen in a particular order and you have no other way of enforcing that.

Answer (score 3):

Late reading this, but..
The way I read your question, you only need to change two lines of code:

Accept user input, function writes back on screen.

```
<input type="text" id="userInput"=> give me input</input>
<button onclick="test()">Submit</button>

<!-- add this line for function to write into -->
<p id="demo"></p>   

<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userInput;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to send/add input tag's values into JavaScript variable which worked well for me, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changef()
            {
            var ctext=document.getElementById("c").value;

            document.writeln(ctext);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="c" onchange="changef"();>

        <button type="button" onclick="changef()">click</button>
    </body> 
</html>
```