# Get user input and use as variable in js

Tags: variables, input

If I copy [this exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305527/javascript-user-input-through-html-input-tag-to-set-a-javascript-variable/44448130#44448130) into my code, it says test undefined. I've tried the code from at least five pages like this and they all give an error. I need to get a number from the user and assign it to a variable in my script.js and then be able to use that variable.

Comment: Please add you code

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what your problem is. I've resimulated it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pyku3nLz/).

Most likely your problem is that you put that piece of code in the head. This causes the function `test()` to be undefined to any HTML. Instead you should include the function in the script tag within the body. So to compare, this will not work and give the error *test is undefined*:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function test() {
                var value = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
                alert(value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Give me a value">
        <button onclick="test();">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Whereas this will:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Give me a value">
        <button onclick="test();">Submit</button>

        <script>
            function test() {
                var value = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
                alert(value);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Separating this in an HTML file and a script file it would look like this (tested and working):

*test.html:*

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="test.js"></script>

        <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Give me a value">
        <button onclick="test();">Submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

*test.js:*

```
function test() {
    var value = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    alert(value);
}
```

Comment: Can I have it in my script.js file? I never add css or js to the html. In my js file is where I have it.

Comment: It's fine but then also make sure to include the script file in the body, not the head.

Comment: Edited the answer. I have this setup working in my browser right now.

Comment: Thanks, I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<button id="sub">submit</button>
<script>
const btn =document.getElementById("sub");
let val;
btn.addEventListener("click",get_val);
function get_val(){
val =
document.getElementById("txt").value;}
//Use it as you want
console.log(val);

</script>
```

Comment: This gives the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration"

Comment: sorry, the val variable must be initialized if marking as 'const', otherwise you can use 'let' to declare a variable that is to be re-initialized. i fixed the code.

Comment: Thanks, I will try again.